# Attempt to invoke virtual method '...(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm very new to android development as I just took a class of it only now, so I'm very confused with my current situation as I am writing the codes using the references I currently have at the moment.

I have also been trying to use references from other sources, though, sadly, I can't really comprehend how those really works.

My current assignment is that I have to make an application that serves as a catalog for movies and tv shows using fragments, and the following is the codes of one of the fragments:

```
public class MovieFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    private String[] titleMovie;
    private String[] descMovie;
    private TypedArray posterMovie;
    private String[] genreMovie;
    private String[] castMovie;
    private String[] duration;
    private String[] directorMovie;
    private MovieAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Movie> movies;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mv_fragment,container,false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.mv_list);
        adapter = new MovieAdapter(getContext(), movies);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()) {});
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        prepare();
        addItem();
    }

    private void prepare() {
        titleMovie = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name_mv);
        descMovie = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.desc_mv);
        posterMovie = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.poster_mv);
        genreMovie = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.genre_mv);
        castMovie = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cast_mv);
        directorMovie = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.director_mv);
        duration = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.duration);
    }

    private void addItem() {
        movies = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < titleMovie.length; i++){
            Movie movie = new Movie();
            movie.setTitleMovie(titleMovie[i]);
            movie.setDescMovie(descMovie[i]);
            movie.setPosterMovie(posterMovie.getResourceId(i,-1));
            movie.setGenreMovie(genreMovie[i]);
            movie.setDuration(duration[i]);
            movie.setDirectorMovie(directorMovie[i]);
            movie.setCastMovie(castMovie[i]);
            movies.add(movie);
        }
        adapter.setMovie(movies);
    }

}
```

And when I try to run the application from the emulator provided in Android Studio, I got the following error:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.wisnu_1605450.utsmobpro, PID: 18250
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.wisnu_1605450.utsmobpro.MovieAdapter.setMovie(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference
    at com.wisnu_1605450.utsmobpro.MovieFragment.addItem(MovieFragment.java:74)
    at com.wisnu_1605450.utsmobpro.MovieFragment.onCreate(MovieFragment.java:47)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2586)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:838)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1197)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1080)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:119)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
```

Any explanation on why I screwed up is very much appreciated, will also give more of the codes if necessary for the context.

Comment: This is because in your `for` loop, as `titleMovies` is not set to any variable, the `for` loop will not execute and hence the `movies` array is null, which results in an error.

Comment: I had the `prepare()` method run first before `addItem()` to have an array for each item in the `addItem()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Fragment Life cycle [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments), `onCreate` event will be called before `onCreateView` event. That mean when you call `adapter.setMovie(movies)`, the adapter is not created. It'll cause a NullPointerException.

You should call `addItem` in `onViewCreated` or `onStart` event.

Answer (score 0):

`OnCreate()` method should be called before `onCreateView()` and after that `onViewCreated()` will be called. 
Whereas in your code `prepare(),addItem()` methods are called in `onCreate()` so that instance not create for your `MovieAdapter()`.please remove `prepare(),addItem()` methods in `onCreate()` and place it `OnViewCreated()`